# C# Bytes String to Bytes Array

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I have following string of bytes

> 17 80 41 00 01 00 01 00 08 00 44 61 72 65 46 61 74 65 01 00 00 00 01 00 03 00 01 00 09 00 43 68 61 6E 6E 65 6C 2D 31 00 00 02 00 09 00 43 68 61 6E 6E 65 6C 2D 32 65 00 03 00 09 00 43 68 61 6E 6E 65 6C 2D 33 65 00

What is the best way to take it as input from user and make it into byte array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
string text = ...
byte[] bytes = text.Split()
                   .Select(t => byte.Parse(t, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
                   .ToArray();
```

If you want to only split on the space-character (rather than any whitespace) use `Split (' ')`.

Comment: +1 This is the "all in one" of what I wrote.  Very pithy, but can be confusing.

Answer (score 8):

If the user is inputting it into the command line just like that, do this:

```
        string input = GetInput(); // this is where you get the input
        string[] numbs = input.Split(' ');
        byte[] array = new byte[numbs.Length];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var numb in numbs)
        {
            array[i++] = byte.Parse(numb, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Parse method in System.Byte to parse the individual hax pairs:

```
// Get the string from the user
string s=Console.ReadLine();

// Convert to a byte array
byte[] sBytes=s.Split(new char[] {' '})
               .Select(hexChar => byte.Parse(hexChar,NumberStyles.HexNumber))
               .ToArray();

// *** Test code follows ***

// Display the bytes (optional), to verify that the conversion worked
StringBuilder hexString=new StringBuilder(sBytes.Length*3);

foreach (byte b in sBytes)     
{
  // Separate hex pairs with a space
  if (hexString.Length>0)
    hexString.Append(' ');
  // Append next hex pair (i.e., formatted byte)
  hexString.AppendFormat("{0:x2}",b);
}

Console.WriteLine(hexString);
```

Comment: Doesn't Encoding.ASCII convert from an ASCII String to bytes, and not from a hex formatted string to bytes?

Comment: I guess I had trouble understanding the question. I've updated my code now that I think I understand what the question author intended.